# Zip arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, zip

I have one 2D array and one 1D array. I would like to zip them together.

```py
import numpy as np

arr2D = [[5.88964708e-02, -2.38142395e-01, -4.95821417e-01, -7.07269274e-01],
         [0.53363666,  0.1654723 , -0.16439857, -0.44880487]]
arr2D = np.asarray(arr2D)

arr1D = np.arange(7, 8.5+0.5, 0.5)
arr1D = np.asarray(arr1D)

res = np.array(list(zip(arr1D, arr2D)))

print(res)
```

which results in:

```py
[[7.0 array([ 0.05889647, -0.2381424 , -0.49582142, -0.70726927])]
 [7.5 array([ 0.53363666,  0.1654723 , -0.16439857, -0.44880487])]]
```

But I am trying to get:

```py
[[(7.0, 0.05889647), (7.5, -0.2381424), (8.0, -0.49582142), (8.5, -0.70726927)]]
[[(7.0, 0.53363666), (7.5, 0.1654723),(8.0, -0.16439857), (8.5, -0.44880487)]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [382]: arr2D = [[5.88964708e-02, -2.38142395e-01, -4.95821417e-01, -7.07269274e-01], 
     ...:          [0.53363666,  0.1654723 , -0.16439857, -0.44880487]] 
     ...: arr2D = np.asarray(arr2D) 
     ...: arr1D = np.arange(7, 8.5+0.5, 0.5)   # already an array                                      


In [384]: arr2D.shape                                                                                  
Out[384]: (2, 4)
In [385]: arr1D.shape                                                                                  
Out[385]: (4,)
```

`zip` iterates on the first dimension of the arguments, and stops with the shortest:

```
In [387]: [[i,j[0:2]] for i,j in zip(arr1D, arr2D)]                                                    
Out[387]: 
[[7.0, array([ 0.05889647, -0.2381424 ])],
 [7.5, array([0.53363666, 0.1654723 ])]]
```

If we transpose the 2d, so it is now (4,2), we get a four element list:

```
In [389]: [[i,j] for i,j in zip(arr1D, arr2D.T)]                                                       
Out[389]: 
[[7.0, array([0.05889647, 0.53363666])],
 [7.5, array([-0.2381424,  0.1654723])],
 [8.0, array([-0.49582142, -0.16439857])],
 [8.5, array([-0.70726927, -0.44880487])]]
```

We could add another level of iteration to get the desired pairs:

```
In [390]: [[(i,k) for k in j] for i,j in zip(arr1D, arr2D.T)]                                          
Out[390]: 
[[(7.0, 0.0588964708), (7.0, 0.53363666)],
 [(7.5, -0.238142395), (7.5, 0.1654723)],
 [(8.0, -0.495821417), (8.0, -0.16439857)],
 [(8.5, -0.707269274), (8.5, -0.44880487)]]
```

and with list transpose idiom:

```
In [391]: list(zip(*_))                                                                                
Out[391]: 
[((7.0, 0.0588964708), (7.5, -0.238142395), (8.0, -0.495821417), (8.5, -0.707269274)),
 ((7.0, 0.53363666), (7.5, 0.1654723), (8.0, -0.16439857), (8.5, -0.44880487))]
```

Or we can get that result directly by moving the `zip` into an inner loop:

```
[[(i,k) for i,k in  zip(arr1D, row)] for row in arr2D]
```

In other words, you are pairing the elements of `arr1D` with the elements of each row of 2D, rather than with the whole row.

Since you already have arrays, one of the array solutions might be better, but I'm trying to clarify what is happening with `zip`.

## numpy

There are various ways of building a numpy array from these arrays.  Since you want to repeat the `arr1D` values:

This `repeat` makes a (4,2) array that matchs `arr2D` (`tile` also works):

```
In [400]: arr1D[None,:].repeat(2,0)                                                                    
Out[400]: 
array([[7. , 7.5, 8. , 8.5],
       [7. , 7.5, 8. , 8.5]])
In [401]: arr2D                                                                                        
Out[401]: 
array([[ 0.05889647, -0.2381424 , -0.49582142, -0.70726927],
       [ 0.53363666,  0.1654723 , -0.16439857, -0.44880487]])
```

which can then be joined on a new trailing axis:

```
In [402]: np.stack((_400, arr2D), axis=2)                                                              
Out[402]: 
array([[[ 7.        ,  0.05889647],
        [ 7.5       , -0.2381424 ],
        [ 8.        , -0.49582142],
        [ 8.5       , -0.70726927]],

       [[ 7.        ,  0.53363666],
        [ 7.5       ,  0.1654723 ],
        [ 8.        , -0.16439857],
        [ 8.5       , -0.44880487]]])
```

Or a structured array with tuple-like display:

```
In [406]: arr = np.zeros((2,4), dtype='f,f')                                                           
In [407]: arr                                                                                          
Out[407]: 
array([[(0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.)],
       [(0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.)]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
In [408]: arr['f1'] = arr2D                                                                            
In [409]: arr['f0'] = _400                                                                             
In [410]: arr                                                                                          
Out[410]: 
array([[(7. ,  0.05889647), (7.5, -0.2381424 ), (8. , -0.49582142),
        (8.5, -0.70726925)],
       [(7. ,  0.5336367 ), (7.5,  0.1654723 ), (8. , -0.16439857),
        (8.5, -0.44880486)]], dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there! Here's a solution:

```
list(map(lambda x: list(zip(arr1D, x)), arr2D))
```

```
[[(7.0, 0.0588964708),
  (7.5, -0.238142395),
  (8.0, -0.495821417),
  (8.5, -0.707269274)],
 [(7.0, 0.53363666), (7.5, 0.1654723), (8.0, -0.16439857), (8.5, -0.44880487)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to expand the 1d array, and then use [numpy.dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html), namely:

```py
import numpy as np

arr2D = np.array([[5.88964708e-02, -2.38142395e-01, -4.95821417e-01, -7.07269274e-01], 
                  [0.53363666,  0.1654723 , -0.16439857, -0.44880487]])
arr1D = np.arange(7, 8.5+0.5, 0.5)

np.dstack([np.tile(arr1D, (2,1)), arr2D])
array([[[ 7.        ,  0.05889647],
        [ 7.5       , -0.2381424 ],
        [ 8.        , -0.49582142],
        [ 8.5       , -0.70726927]],

       [[ 7.        ,  0.53363666],
        [ 7.5       ,  0.1654723 ],
        [ 8.        , -0.16439857],
        [ 8.5       , -0.44880487]]])
```